# Ionic 3 application not working on physical android device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

> **Ionic 3 applications not running on physical device for testing.**

```
    After downloading the default application, using 
    `ionic start app_name sidemenu`
    I plugged in my physical Android device for debugging.
    When i executing the command `ionic cordova run android`,
    I only see the flash then after few seconds a blank screen.
    When trying to debug, i realize there is a java-script error.
```

[image: This is the error i got when debugging from the physical device(android phone)]
Please,Suggestion would be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to host your `api` and replace the path with domain name in `http` calls.

**Or**

If you are using local network use local network IP address and make sure your firewall is OFF.

Replace location host with IP address i.e `192.168.1.X:53703`

Comment: thanks for the comment.
Where can i find the host IP that i need to amend?
I already turn off my firewall.
Thanks

Comment: open command prompt and run `ipconfig` and find `IPv4 Address`

Comment: I have my local IP already, now i need to change from localhost to my IP address. Is there some part of the ionic codes that  needs to change? to take into account my IP address ?

Comment: Change your where you are making http call.